# converting MATLAB code to Fortran

Tags: matlab, translation, fortran, macos

I a medical researcher with code written in MATLAB 2009b that runs very slowly because of a self-referential loop (not sure of the programming lingo here), i.e., the results of the first iteration is used during the second iteration, etc.  (I have vectorized it to a fare-thee-well.  I have run the Profiler.)

I'd like to convert the slow parts of the code to a mex function. I learned Fortran in the early 1970s but haven't used it since.  The code I need to convert doesn't do anything fancy, it is just a long numerical calculation.

My question is: what would be the easiest-to-relearn version of Fortran adequate for this purpose, and what compiler works best on the Intel Mac for this?  I found information comparing  syntax in MATLAB to Fortran 90 for example, and the conversion doesn't look like it would be too daunting for me.  However, again, I am no programmer.

I am using a MacBook Pro with OS 10.6.

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: How ironic.  Matlab was developed in part as a "better" FORTRAN.

Comment: Is the code small enough to post? There may still be other optimizations before resorting to MEX. E.g. preallocation and being careful with function calls could allow newer Matlabs to do in-place array modification, a big win for iterative calculations.

Comment: lets hope this heated discussion didn't scare him off :)

Comment: @Marc - no, MATLAB was developed for people who didn't wish to learn fortran (specifically, control design engineers), and still wanted to use itd libraries, such as LINPACK and EISPACK.

Comment: Maybe some CPU-generations and MATLAB-versions later, this code runs fast now...

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend using modern Fortran, at least 90/95 as the syntax is much more forgiving and almost all compilers now support it.

On a Mac I would recommend gfortran from [here](http://r.research.att.com/tools/). It's not the most recent version, but it's well integrated with Apple build tools (you will need to install Xcode from your Mac OS DVD) and works well. In the numerical python community, which depends a lot of Fortran extensions, this build is highly recommended.

I haven't actually used fortran mex on the mac - but I think it should be fairly straightforward if you follow the mex documentation - and as you say translating code from Matlab to Fortran shouldn't be too bad (it's better if you can avoid calling Matlab functions, but fortran has sensible slicing and array access).

Comment: Downvote with no comment? I think I answered the question...

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. I think the advice is good (pretty much the thing I was gonna say), only some people here don't like some languages, therefore the downvote (guessing).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have probably found a solution already.  However, I will say this:  Matlab has been getting faster and faster.  However making full use of Matlab's JIT is sometimes not intuitive.  Mathworks used to say vectorize code for speed.  Then they said write everything in explicit loops.  I'm actually not certain what the current best practice is.

What I'm saying is, before you go to fortran, find out the best practice and implement it.  That may give you enough of a speed-up right there.

Also, are you absolutely certain that you have isolated the slowdown to a loop?  Have you been using the profiler?  You probably have, since you sound experienced.  I just thought I'd mention it.

Good luck,
Ariel